# Is there a way to tell the clang analyser that a function returns malloc()'ed memory?

Tags: c, clang

I am working on a small library where I don't want to deal with allocation errors everywhere they might pop up, so I've written a wrapper around `malloc()` that terminates the program (for now) if an error occurs.

```c
void *cstr_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *buf = malloc(size);
    if (!buf)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation error, terminating\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Nothing fancy there. Now, however, I noticed that the clang static analyzer, in Xcode at least, doesn't catch obvious leaks that it would have done before.

If I do something like this:

```c
void foo(void)
{
    void *p = malloc(100);
}
```

it would naturally inform me that `p` would likely leak memory.

However, with

```c
void foo(void)
{
    void *p = malloc(100);
    void *q = cstr_malloc(100);
}
```

it only reports that `p`, but not `q`, is leaking.

That makes sense; it can't know everywhere the program might allocate memory and still analyse it in a reasonable time. It handles my allocator fine if I inline it, so there it can see it, but otherwise, it doesn't.

Is there any way to tell the analyser that I have a function that returns freshly allocated memory? Some attribute, like `__attribute__((malloc))` or similar?

I can, of course, just inline the function, but I have a bunch of other functions that similarly allocate memory, and it would be problematic to inline *all* of them.

Comment: @P.P Doesn't seem to work though: https://godbolt.org/z/9o19esbhG

Comment: I did try __attribute__((malloc)) but it work for me. Of course, there could easily be something else wrong and that is why I am not seeing an effect. But the attribute alone didn't do the trick while inlining the allocator did...

Comment: Hmm, @P.P on Godbolt it works for me (but not on my own machine). Should I understand it such that it doesn't work for you on Godbolt? Then it might be a configuration issue I need to figure out. EDIT: nope, I misread Godbolt. It doesn't work there either.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I only see a warning for the allocated `p`, not the (equally allocated) `q`. It doesn't see (and here, of course, can't see) that `q` is also allocated memory.

Comment: Yeah, never mind that comment. The warning text mentions `p`, but the code highlight under it is on `q`. Confusing stuff.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica that's also how I misread it the first time.

Answer (score 3):

After some hours of googling, I found what at least looks like a solution. The trick is indeed to use an attribute, but not `__attribute__((malloc))`.

The attribute I needed was `ownership_returns(malloc)`. Using that, I get warnings, at least for this function.

```c
__attribute__((ownership_returns(malloc)))
void *cstr_malloc(size_t size);
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/MEfvThKnW

Unfortunately, my joy was short-lived. If I use `ownership_returns(malloc)`, then the analyser will assume that the memory is also uninitialised, which it isn't always. I have no idea how to hint that I return memory that must be freed, but *not* uninitialised memory.

Since `clang` can figure out that this is the case for `calloc()`, there might be a way to do it for my functions as well, but I haven't found it.

Here is an example of how `clang` deals with memory returned from `calloc()` and what it thinks of what comes from my own function: https://godbolt.org/z/P45o691Tx